# Removing the skip buttons from the flash source

Tags: actionscript-3, mp3, flash

I am no flash expert however I need to edit the source of the flash project here: http://tools.assembla.com/1pixelout/browser/audio-player/

It's the "Wordpress audio player" I need to remove the skip forward and back buttons when there is more than one audio file.

Anyone know how to first of all use this folder structure, I thought it would simply be a .fla file that you edit but it seems to be loads of files. And then how do I compile it?

Thanks in advance,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be FLA-based, meaning you will need to purchase a copy of Flash Professional (what version you need depends on the version of the FLA file).

It depends on how it was coded, either you need to edit the graphics / layout inside the FLA file, or you need to edit the code in one of the classes. The classes can either be embedded in the FLA file, or they can be in separate standalone AS files.

Comment: How would I open this as a .fla? would i need to download it all then change the folder to a .fla? When I embed the player it's all in just one swf or does the as files get compiled in when exporting it?

Comment: You double-click the FLA file and it opens in Flash Pro. When you compile it, it will take the FLA and all the extra classes and output a single SWF.